# Safari meta name viewport specific

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, viewport, meta

I have non-standard-problem
I have site for iphone/ipad.

I have in meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640"/>
```

and all is well open.

BUT! I go to the link on the inner section of the site. Then I press the "back" (for iphone, for ipad - the browser is Safari)

And when it works "backwards" - you get back to the main page and the entire site is flattened by half, if it stands

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
```

p.s.
Option with `width = device-width` disappears for a little make-up initially incorrectly made​​.

Comment: The other webpage, the one you go to through the link, does it have the very same `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640"/>` element?

Comment: all pages have  content="width=640"/>. But now i used:            var orient = Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'; 
    if( orient == 'landscape' ){
           var viewPortScale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;
           $('head meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, minimum-scale='+ viewPortScale+', initial-scale='+viewPortScale);     and its nice work in "portrait". But bad work in "landspace"